# How to embed a public report using filters?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-filters

I would like to embed a report in my website, using filters and i want this report to be public

I saw that you can use the "Publish to web" option to do that but you can't use filters (I read that but i'm not sure)

and with the new "Embed" option you can filter but you need to have a account to see the report.

Is there a way to do both filtering and enable access to anyone on the internet ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use "Publish to web" the filtering pane will not be visible, but you can always add slicers to your report, which will allow your visitors to filter the data.

The proper way to do this is to [actually embed the report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers) into your site. You can see it in action in [Power BI Embedded Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html). When embedding, there are two scenarios - "user owns data", in which each visitor needs Power BI Pro account to see the report, and "app owns data", in which your application uses one Power BI Pro account to authenticate itself, but your users don't need to have Power BI accounts at all. In your case you need the later one.

Simply download Microsoft's [sample application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers#embed-content-using-the-sample-application) and configure it. You need to [register Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/register-app) to be used in your app. Then your app will [authenticate itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token#access-token-for-non-power-bi-users-app-owns-data) and use [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/) to get report's [`embedUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreportingroup#definitions) and use it with [Power BI JavaScript client](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) to embed it in an empty `<div>` in a web page.